# CKEditor setData() changes content but throws error

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following text area defined in my JSP page:

```
<textarea id="edit_subtaskstep_notes" name="edit_subtaskstep_notes" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
```

In my js file I am setting the content data as such:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.edit_subtaskstep_notes.setData("Hello World");
```

This successfully sets the ckeditor text box to contain "Hello World" when run but after this line is executed the following error is thrown in my output window:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (14:21:03:488 | error, javascript)
at (anonymous function) (:197:29)
```

If I remove that line the error goes away but the data is no longer set. As it "seems" to work since the data is getting set is this some kind of bug with CKEditor v4? The download readme just says "CKEditor 4" but the linked version (which does not throw the error) says 4.4.7.

I've simplified the code to the following single file that still reproduces the error. The online version of the include gets rid of the error message. The downloaded version throws the error. I have not modified the download package in any way. As I stated before it still "works" I just don't like error messages:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var editInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
        });

        function onClickChangeText() {
            CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData("Hello World");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea name="editor1" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea><br/>
    <button onclick="onClickChangeText()">Change Text</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the version of CKEditor? Config? List of loaded plugins? Sample to reproduce the issue (i.e. JSFiddle) would be the best.

Comment: I edited to show a simpler example. I can't use JSFiddle because I think the problem is with their downloadable package because linking to the online version eliminates the thrown error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Quickstart guide in the CKeditor download area it said to put the unzipped package in the root of the website. I had tried putting it in a sub-directory and linking to it from there. I'm guessing the main js file tries to link to the other resources it needs internally based off of root which would explain the partial functionality I was experiencing. After moving it to the root the error went away.

Comment: Yes but I'm not doing any of those things. It started throwing that error on me again. It works fine if I include the online version but I still get that error when using their download package for Basic. I unzipped and put into root just as instructed. I'm still clueless but since it works I guess I'll just ignore the error.

Comment: So maybe it's just a browser cache? Did you clear it?

Comment: I've been clearing the cache religiously in between each attempt.

Comment: Then unfortunately I'm clueless too. I would need to see it. The important question is where the error is thrown in the code. You can try the in unminified version.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CKEditor Sample</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
    var editInstance;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        editInstance = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    });

    function onClickChangeText() {
        editInstance.setData("Hello World");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="editor1" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea><br/>
    <button onclick="onClickChangeText()">Change Text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried it out with above sample code works fine for me in all browsers. No errors found in the console.